# SOAP from TSQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, web-services, soap

I like to get some info from this web service: http://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok.asmx?wsdl

The info I need is the result of the `GetCurrentExchangeRates` method.

I test it with SoapUI, with this request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetCurrentExchangeRates/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I got the correct response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse xmlns="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult><![CDATA[<MNBCurrentExchangeRates><Day date="2017-01-06"><Rate unit="1" curr="AUD">212,76</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="BGN">157,05</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="BRL">90,57</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="CAD">218,75</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="CHF">286,65</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="CNY">41,83</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="CZK">11,37</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="DKK">41,32</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="EUR">307,16</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="GBP">358,91</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="HKD">37,36</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="HRK">40,53</Rate><Rate unit="100" curr="IDR">2,17</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="ILS">75,42</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="INR">4,26</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="ISK">2,56</Rate><Rate unit="100" curr="JPY">249,83</Rate><Rate unit="100" curr="KRW">24,27</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="MXN">13,58</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="MYR">64,78</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="NOK">34,12</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="NZD">203,58</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="PHP">5,87</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="PLN">70,45</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="RON">68,17</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="RSD">2,48</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="RUB">4,88</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="SEK">32,16</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="SGD">202,09</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="THB">8,12</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="TRY">80,08</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="UAH">10,74</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="USD">289,75</Rate><Rate unit="1" curr="ZAR">21,26</Rate></Day></MNBCurrentExchangeRates>]]></GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult>
      </GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I try to read this information from SQL Server this way (I create a procedure for it, see the code below)

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[spHTTPRequest] 
      @URI varchar(2000) = '',      
      @methodName varchar(50) = '', 
      @requestBody varchar(8000) = '', 
      @SoapAction varchar(255), 
      @UserName nvarchar(100), -- Domain\UserName or UserName 
      @Password nvarchar(100), 
      @responseText varchar(8000) output
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @methodName = ''
    BEGIN
      select FailPoint = 'Method Name must be set'
      return
    END

    SET @responseText = 'FAILED'

    DECLARE @objectID int
    DECLARE @hResult int
    DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255) 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @objectID OUT
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                  source = @source, 
                  description = @desc, 
                  FailPoint = 'Create failed', 
                  MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
-- open the destination URI with Specified method 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @URI, 'false', @UserName, @Password
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'Open failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
-- set request headers 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
-- set soap action 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'SOAPAction', @SoapAction 
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
declare @len int
set @len = len(@requestBody) 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len 
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END

-- send the request 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null, @requestBody 
IF    @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'Send failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
declare @statusText varchar(1000), @status varchar(1000) 
-- Get status text 
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'StatusText', @statusText out
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'Status', @status out
select @status, @statusText, @methodName 
-- Get response text 
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText', @responseText out
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'ResponseText failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
destroy: 
      exec sp_OADestroy @objectID 
SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO
*/

declare @xmlOut varchar(8000)
Declare @RequestText as varchar(8000);
set @RequestText=
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <web:GetCurrentExchangeRates/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

exec spHTTPRequest 'http://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok.asmx?wsdl', 'post', @RequestText,'http://tempuri.org/CreateOrderForMe','', '', @xmlOut out
```

But I always get an "Internal server" error. Can somebody suggest me a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the error?

Comment: GOTOs??? Really??? And why do you have code after the goto?

Comment: I got HTTP500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: What's the problem with goto? I write return after it, just for peace of mind ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue while executing my procedure. There seems to be some difference in the MSXML2.HTTP method between Windows 2012 and windows 2007. For example the send works as follows in 2012:

```
DECLARE @send NVARCHAR(4000) = 'send("' + REPLACE(@requestBody, '"', '''') + '")';
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, @send
```

unlike

```
sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null, @requestBody
```

in your procedure.

Comment: Thanks, finaly I use something similar :)